# Interactive Brokers API (IBAPI) reqMktData returns same number for auction volume and auction imbalance

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

**2nd UPDATE:** Actually, it appears that the bug might even be in the stream provided by the ASX, since TWS appears to be simply passing that data straight through to the user. This would explain why this hasn't been picked up before - because it might be unique to just the Australian Stock Exchange.

**UPDATE:** I've managed to prove that this is actually a bug in TWS itself, and has nothing to do with the API. I've filed a bug report with IB and will close this question.

I'm using IBAPI with Python and I make the following call:

```
self.reqMktData(idnum, contract1, 'mdoff,225', False, False, [])
```

My understanding is that this is supposed to return the auction price, auction volume, and auction imbalance (tick types 34, 35, and 36). I do indeed get a return value for each tick type. However, the return I get for tick types 35 and 36 (auction volume and auction imbalance) is always the same number (which obviously they shouldn't be). Other than this, everything looks correct - specifically the auction price and volume data matches the order book data (obtained separately).

This is for data from the Australian Stock Exchange, and I'm getting the behaviour across all stocks and time periods I've investigated (which is quite a few).

Anyone else experienced this problem?

I've pasted an MWE below for anyone who wants to quickly reproduce the behaviour (note, you may or may not need to adjust connection IP and port number):

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import Order
from ibapi.order_state import OrderState

import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
import queue
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
        def __init__(self):
                EClient.__init__(self, self)
        def request_auction_data_single(self, idnum: int, contract1: Contract):
                self.reqMktData(idnum, contract1, 'mdoff,225', False, False, []) #225 is tick id for auction data of volume, price, and imbalance
                return None
        def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
                # tick price data sent by TWS is received by this function
                attrib_as_string = str(attrib)
                print("tickPrice triggered. reqId=%d, tickType=%d, price=%f, attribasstr=%s" % (reqId, tickType, price, attrib_as_string))
                return None
        def tickSize(self, reqId, tickType, size):
                # tick size data sent by TWS is received by this function
                print("tickSize  triggered. reqId=%d, tickType=%d, size=%d" % (reqId, tickType, size))
                return None
        def error(self, id, errorCode, errorString):
                errormessage = "TWS error. id = %d. errorcode = %d. msg = %s" % (id, errorCode, errorString)
                print(errormessage)
        def build_contract(self, mkt: str, scy: str, sectype: str, currency: str):
                cc1 = Contract()
                cc1.exchange = mkt
                cc1.symbol = scy
                cc1.secType = sectype
                cc1.currency = currency
                return cc1

def run_loop():
        app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0)

# Start the app in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) # Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

# Request auction data
id1 = app.reqIds(-1)
contract1 = app.build_contract("ASX","NAB","STK","AUD")
app.request_auction_data_single(id1, contract1)
```

Just run this snippet in a pre-auction period and you'll see what I mean.

**EDIT:** I've filed an issue on the projects github page, but access is restricted so not much point adding a link here.

Comment: That's a tough question, and I'd ask it on the [TWS API forum](https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topics). I'm sure someone there can help.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino Thanks, I'll put together a MWE and post it there. I was wondering if this is a common issue, but sounds like it is not.

Comment: Are you requesting the auction info during the auction process?

Comment: @misantroop Yes, definitely. It returns `nothing` if you request outside the pre-auction period.

Comment: If your data subscriptions are as required, it's likely a bug.

Comment: @misantroop Yeah, I think so too. I'll put together a MWE and file an issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have determined that the problem described is in fact a bug in TWS itself, rather than having anything to do with the API. I've submitted a bug report so there is not much else to say on the matter.